# SWT, TypedEvent: how to make use of the time variable

Tags: swt

The `TypedEvent` class has the member variable `time`. I want to use it to discard too old events. Unfortunately, it is of type `int` where as `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns `long` and both are very different, even when masking them with `0xFFFFFFFFL` as the JavaDoc of `time` is telling me. How should the `time` be interpreted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** As you haven't mentioned the operating system therefore I am safely assuming it as Windows (because this is what I have got).

---

**Answer**

If you closely look at the `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget` class then you will find that `TypedEvent.time` is initialized as follows:

```
event.time = display.getLastEventTime ();
```

Which in return calls: `OS.GetMessageTime ();`

Now, `SWT` directly works with **OS widgets** therefore on a windows machine the call `OS.GetMessageTime ();` directly translates to **Windows GetMessageTime** API.

Check the [GetMessageTime on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). As per the page:

> Retrieves the message time for the
>   last message retrieved by the
>   GetMessage function. The time is a
>   long integer that specifies the
>   elapsed time, in milliseconds, from
>   the time the system was started to the
>   time the message was created (that is,
>   placed in the thread's message queue).

Pay special attention to the line **`from the time the system was started to the time the message was created`**, which means it is not the standard `System.currentTimeMillis()` which is the elapsed time, in milliseconds, since 1, Jan 1970.

> Also, To calculate time delays between
>   messages, verify that the time of the
>   second message is greater than the
>   time of the first message; then,
>   subtract the time of the first message
>   from the time of the second message.

See the below example code, which prints two different messages for time **less than** 5 seconds and **greater than** 5 seconds. (**Note:** It should be noted that the timer starts with the first event. So the calculation is **always relative** with-respect-to first event). Because of its relative nature the `TypedEvent.time` might not be suitable for your purpose as the first event may come very late.

**>> Code**

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class ControlF 
{
    static Calendar first = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Display display = new Display ();

        final Shell shell = new Shell (display);
        shell.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            }
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
            {
                long eventTime = (e.time&0xFFFFFFFFL) ;
                if(first == null)
                { 
                    System.out.println("in");
                    first = Calendar.getInstance();
                    first.setTimeInMillis(eventTime);
                }

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTimeInMillis(eventTime);

                long dif = (cal.getTimeInMillis() - first.getTimeInMillis())/1000;
                if( dif <= 5)
                {
                    System.out.println("Within 5 secs [" + dif + "]");
                }else
                    System.out.println("Oops!! out of 5 second range !!");              
            }
        });

        shell.setSize (200, 200);
        shell.open ();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
        }
        display.dispose ();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so far. Is there also a Java method which I can use to calculate the difference between the current time and the event time, so I easily can discard events (e.g. button clicks) which are too old?

Comment: @Mike L.: Well `old` is a relative term. If your reference is the start of your application then you can initialize some time keeping variable there, if reference is some event then you can start your time keeper there. As far as some standard library or function is concerned, i haven't used one. You can float it as a question on SO. There are many java experts who might help you. good luck